# Change specific image style after it was drawn on screen

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am building a small menu in my `LibGDX` app.
I have some buttons, that I draw from the same resource, and over them I puts different image labels.
after I created the buttons I'm looking for a way to updated them.

I run in a loop for 10 times,creates `ImageButtom` and adding it as `Actor`

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++ ) {

        ImageButtonStyle style = new ImageButtonStyle() ;
        style.up = skin.getDrawable(i);
        style.down = skin.getDrawable(i);
        ImageButton image = new ImageButton(styleButton);
        addActor(image);     
        }
```

as a result I have 10 buttons with different images-labels on them.
when I have an event to update an button image (change from disable/enable/pressed..)
I don't have a way to get X image and change it, because I added them without any `TAG`, or any `id`.

I can draw it again, to remove all and them draw it in the loop again, but I think it wont be the best way to implement it.

I'm looking for a way to manage it...

Answer (score 0):

not if I understood what you want, or if this is either the most efficient way, but which I happened to read your question:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++ ) {

    ImageButtonStyle style = new ImageButtonStyle() ;
    style.up               = skin.getDrawable(i);
    style.down             = skin.getDrawable(i);
    ImageButton image      = new ImageButton(styleButton);

    image.setName("styleNumber"+i); // or use Integer.toString(i);

    addActor(image);     
    }
```

.

```
private void testStageActorByName(String name) {

    String tempName = name; //-> e.g: "styleNumber1"

    for (int a = 0; a < yourStage.size; a++) {
        if (yourStage.get(a).getName().equals(tempName)) {

        //what you want to do, change something in that actor "styleNumber1"
            yourStage.get(a)...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the image in an Array or other structure:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;

Array<ImageButton> myImageButtons = new Array<ImageButton>(10);


for (int i=0; i<10; i++ ) {
        ImageButtonStyle style = new ImageButtonStyle() ;
        style.up = skin.getDrawable(i);
        style.down = skin.getDrawable(i);
        ImageButton image = new ImageButton(styleButton);
        addActor(image);     

        myImageButtons.add(image);
}
```

Then you can look it up later:

```
void ImageButton getButtonImage(int i) {
    return myImageButtons.get(i);
}
```